# Bind port in docker-compose.yml doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a NodeJS and React application made with a docker-compose.yml and I'm trying to put my application on port `:8090`, but when I do a `curl`, I get this error

```
curl localhost:8090
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      args:
        # Variaveis do frontend
        - BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8090
    restart: always
    container_name: petcertificados
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./certificados:/usr/app/server/certificados
```

If I go inside my container, I can access my website, but not if I'm outside

```
[root@blastoise certificados]# docker exec -it petcertificados /bin/bash
root@a0d690c11c38:/usr/app/server# curl localhost:8080/api
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Certificados - Backend</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Certificados - BackEnd</h3>
  </body>
```

Because in my personal computer this works, I think it may be a error with the docker in the machine. The docker version is `Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d` and I'm in a CentOS. I tried to restart the docker with `service docker restart` but doesn't work and I don't have ideia of what could be.

**[EDIT 1]** My index.js where I set up the port configuration and start the application

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors')

const { BACKEND_PORT } = require("./constants/index.js");

const CLIENT_BUILD_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build');
app.use(express.static(CLIENT_BUILD_PATH));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    next();
})

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/api/certificados', require('./routes/Certificados'));
app.use('/api/eventos', require('./routes/Eventos'));

app.listen(BACKEND_PORT, () => { 
    console.info(`Iniciando PETCertificados!`)
});
```

I tried to put "0.0.0.0" but this is already the default on NodeJS

**[EDIT 2]**
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.5.0 as frontend

WORKDIR /usr/app/frontend

COPY frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm install -qy

COPY frontend/ ./

ARG BACKEND_URL
ENV REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL ${BACKEND_URL}

RUN npm run build

FROM node:14.5.0
WORKDIR /usr/app/ 

COPY --from=frontend /usr/app/frontend/build ./frontend/build

WORKDIR /usr/app/server/
COPY backend/package*.json ./

RUN npm install -qy
COPY backend/ ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the the application code, at least to the point where it sets up a network listener?  A common cause of this problem is the application binding to the container-private localhost interface 127.0.0.1, when it need to bind to all interfaces 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes! I included this informations!

Comment: Your Dockerfile would also help here

Comment: @JaredBeach it's there!

Comment: Try adding `EXPOSE 8080` to your dockerfile

Comment: @JaredBeach Didn't work :/

Step 16/17 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in cae6b33ac028
Step 17/17 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Running in 9ad62e6e8327
Successfully built 8f15ce41d67b
Successfully tagged certificados_web:latest
Creating petcertificados
[root@blastoise certificados]# docker-compose up -d
petcertificados is up-to-date
[root@blastoise certificados]# curl localhost:8090
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 0):

With a slightly modified Dockerfile / app.js, I am able to curl localhost:8090 and get a response.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

App.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors')

const CLIENT_BUILD_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build');
app.use(express.static(CLIENT_BUILD_PATH));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    next();
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world!')
});

app.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', () => { 
    console.info(`Iniciando PETCertificados!`)
});
```

docker-compose.yml stays the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. 
`EXPOSE 8080; CMD ["npm", "start"]`
and 
`app.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', () => { 
    console.info("Iniciando PETCertificados!")
});`
I still get 
`[root@blastoise certificados]# curl localhost:8090
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` 
May be the problem isn't in the code, something about my machine?

Comment: possibly. If you don't have anything already running on your physical machine's 8080 port, try mapping to that instead of 8090. So "8080:8080". See if the port is the issue. Otherwise, try getting rid of everything in the docker file except for the backend (react app for example) and see if it works then